# merge back what once was reverted

Tags: svn

I had a bad commit what I reverted by `svn merge -c -1160 .`, then it's time to try with the commit again so I wanted to merge the revision #1160 back to the HEAD but couldn't find the solution after googling. I tried `svn merge -c 1160 .` (the first without the "-" sign) but had no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean; You reverted some work you did to a previous revision, committed that, and now want to merge that back to a different branch?

Comment: @AlG kinda.. made some changes, commited to trunk, needed to revert it asap, now there's time to fix the commit so I want to merge/apply these changes again on trunk. I don't have that changes in my lc a.t.m :/

Comment: When you did `svn merge -c 1160 .`, you reverted rev 1160, but after commit, that was another revision, let's say 1161. So, I would try to reverse merge that revision: `svn merge -c 1161 .`

Comment: Thanks for the remarks, but neither worked, after applying the command nothing happens, and my files are unaffected :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
svn merge -c 1160 . --ignore-ancestry
```