# How do you redo reverts on Svn?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, undo-redo, svncommit

How Can i redo reverts on Svn?

Comment: You cannot normally "undo" a commit in SVN, although you can "reverse" changes from a previous commit into a new commit. You can also easily see the history... that is just basic usage.

Comment: and can i redo if i reversed a commit?

Comment: I think if you want to "undo" something, you would not want to "redo" exactly the same thing, so instead you would code whatever changes you *actually* need as a new commit.

Comment: I just ask because for example someone reverts a a whole commit when he wants just to revert one folder of a commit but he is tired or etc. and makes the mistake...

Comment: I'm editing the question a bit

Comment: An `svn revert` cannot be undone unless you made a local copy of the changed files before you reverted. If you're trying to undo an operation that was committed to the repository, you'll need to be more clear with your question.

Comment: thanks for the answer

Comment: Yes, you can redo a previously reverted commit. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29495053/merge-back-what-once-was-reverted/29518273#29518273

Comment: Possible duplicate of [merge back what once was reverted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29495053/merge-back-what-once-was-reverted)